# Where is the TVSV valve located in a Toyota Tercel 1987?

Tags: thermostat, vacuum

My car is a 1987 Toyota Tercel DX Wagon 1452cc 2bl manual driven car.

It seems now it doesn't have a TVSV, Thermostatic Vacuum Switching Valve. I need it to activate the AAP Pump and the Choke Pull Off.

Can I add any TVSV valve commercially available?

What is the location of the TVSV valve in my vehicle?

Comment: Why do you mean by "TVSV" valve? Are you referring to the Vacuum Switching Valve (VSV)?

Comment: @kyle_engineer Thermostatic Vacuum Switching Valve

Comment: How did these items function before? Was the valve there before and if so, who removed it and why?

Answer (score 2):

**TVSV**

Thermostatic Vacuum Switching Valve (TVSV) is to open manifold vacuum supply at certain temperatures. Vacuum operated devices particularly those connected to the carburetor, are switched "On" by TVSV. These vacuum operated devices are needed to optimize the carburetor function.

Carburetor can work without vacuum operated devices, but in poor efficiency.

[image: image1]

[image]

Earlier I couldn't find the TVSV in my car. Later I found it on the top of the coolent. But it was damaged and the top "pipe connecting part" broken off.

[image]

This was confirmed with the [manual](http://www.toyodiy.com/parts/p_G_1987_TOYOTA_TERCEL_AL25RG-ZWFDS_1708.2.html).

[image]

Comment: According to the top image you show - it needs to be heated by coolant. So where should it be fitted and is there any hot coolant pipes down by the shock absorber?

Comment: @SolarMike , I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solar Mike: In case you're still waiting for an answer...The TVSV for 1983-1988 Tercels is mounted between the temperature sender (on its left, viewed from in front) and the water pump (on its right). The casting it mounts on carries hot coolant.

The diagram shows locations accurately but renders most of the non-vacuum components transparent. None of these parts are close to a shock absorber or strut.